# "Call of overloaded function is ambiguous" even with different argument order

Tags: c++

I have a function `fun()` I wish to overload in the same scope. As per the rules of overloading, different order of arguments should allow for the overloading of the function as mentioned [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-function-overloading/#:%7E:text=Function%20overloading%20is%20a%20C%2B%2B,(int%2C%20float)%20which%20is).

The Code:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
void fun(int i, float j)
{
        cout << "int,float";
}

void fun(float i, int j)
{
        cout << "float,int";
}

int main()
{
        fun(20,20);
}
```

Error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘fun(int, int)’ is ambiguous
   15 |         fun(20,20);
```

Question:

Had there been only one function with argument **fun(int, float)**, that would have been called as the best match, so why does it throw error in this case.

Comment: Which one do you want? `fun(20, 20.f)` or `fun(20.f, 20)`?

Comment: Which `20` should be converted to `float`? First or second? Compiler can't decide on its own, both would be as good, so it's ambiguous

Comment: "Different order of arguments should allow for the overloading of the function" -- yes, insofar as **identical** orders of arguments (rather, argument *types*) does not allow for overloading *at all*. Your ambiguity comes, not from the *definition* of the overload, but from the *calling* of the overload. The example in your tutorial assumes that you are *calling* those functions with either `double, int` or `int, double`.

Comment: @DevSolar So bear with me on this. **Now** I understand the type conversion would virtually be same. However, there would be some order of preference right? My understanding from reading [Microsoft Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/function-overloading?view=msvc-160#argument-matching) was that it would first match the first argument. Or does that example not account for such case?

Comment: @inarticulatus: no, that is not how function overloads are resolved. The two candidates are equally good, so the call is ambiguous. (Your Microsoft link says nothing about treating the first argument differently.)

Comment: @TonyK I was referring to the example with Variant 1, 2, and 3, where they choose Variant 1 and 3 based on the fact that first argument in both Variant 1 and 3 are Fractions

Comment: OT: it should be `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include "iostream"`

Comment: I was using g++ compiler and the example I followed had written it that way, is it a convention to write <> and not " "

Comment: Set 1 considers the first argument, and Set 2 considers the second. So the two arguments are treated identically.

Comment: @inarticulatus: Generally `<>` is for the standard library (and may not be actually a file), `""` for everything else. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266/60281) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give two integers, so the compiler have to convert one into a float, but which function shall be taken?

```
int main()
{
  fun(20.0,20);
  fun( 20, 20.0);
}
```

these calls makes the compiler happy, since you tell which function shall be taken.

Comment: Those floating point literals are not single precision (float) but double. 20.0 is double and 20.0f is single precision literal.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are facing this error is due to the data type of the arguments you have provided
In this case

```
fun(20,20);
```

which are both int, int.

A correct function call in this scenario would be,

```
fun(20,20.0);
```

or

```
fun(20.0,20);
```

(edit)
as mentioned by [Ivan Vnucec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13789930/ivan-vnucec)
it would be better to explicitly call the function with arguments that are float instead of double
so call it in this way:

```
fun(20,20.0f);
```

or

```
fun(20.0f,20);
```